# PHP 500 internal error session_start

Tags: php, session

I get 500 internal error for session_start(). I thought that the fault of session.use_cookies_only set to true (didn't test this), but from root folder session is acting normally. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look into the `error.log`?

Comment: @bish It should be in the same folder where script is? There are no error logs anywhere.

Comment: It should be there where your web server stores it's error log. I think Ubunto this is `/var/log/apache2/` for apache2. But I'm not quite sure as our web servers stores its logs in a specified location.

Comment: @bish Problem is that I don't have access to sever, except the root of website (some kind of virtual host). It is a Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get more detailed information about the error with this code:

https://snippet.land/code/php-500-error-info.9ecf7

In short:
Create a new file (for example `mycode.php`) and paste your code in.
Then, in your current file, replace your code with `require_once("mycode.php");`

Surround this line with a try-catch-block and catch the `Throwable` error.
This gives you detailed information about line, file, stacktrace and more.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error today as well, and the problem turned out to be that my PHP error log had grown to over 37 GB in size.  I guess for some reason that made it hard for PHP to create a new session.  As soon as I deleted the error log file, I was able to create my session.

Comment: Please stop writing duplicated answers.

Comment: If there are duplicate questions, all looking for the same answer, they should all get the same answer.  Somebody looking for a solution might not find the other question, but find this one.  I'm just trying to help others out there who are struggling with this stuff.